# Exclude datamember when using renderJSON with play framework

Tags: java, json, playframework, gson

I need to render objects in JSON and send them to the client but I need to exclude fields like email and password for obvious reasons.

I know play uses GSON (by google?) and you can pass a serializer class when calling the renderJSON() method. However I'm rendering different types of classes at once using a container class:

```
public class JSONContainer {

    public List<User> userList;

    public List<Toy> toyList;

}
```

For each class it's possible to make a Serializer class implementing GSON's `JsonSerializer<...>` method. But if I render a JSONContainer object like this: `renderJSON(container)` how can I pass the serializer classes to the rendering method?

Or is there maybe an easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739769/prevent-certain-fields-from-being-serialized), which gives you a couple of options.

It would appear that the best option is to the @Expose (`com.google.gson.annotations.Expose`) annotation to mark the fields that you want to be serialised by Gson. You then need to use the GsonBuilder to specifically only include the @Expose fields.

Alternatively, as you have mentioned in your post, you can simply build your serialisations yourself. If you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522169/customizing-json-serialization-in-play), it shows how specific class types are registered against the GsonBuilder, so any object of that found as part of the serialisation will use your specific serialiser.

Comment: I went with the `@Expose` way. Thanks